# Problema con parámetros en Java

Tags: java

Estoy teniendo un problema al intentar acceder y comprobar los parámetros pasados por la terminal al ejecutar el programa.
La cosa es que tengo este código:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        BufferedReader buffer;
        FileReader urls;
        String line, arg;
        int count = 0;
        try {
            if( args.length > 0){
                if(args[0] == "-f"){
                    urls = new FileReader(args[1]);
                    buffer = new BufferedReader(urls);

                    while ((  line = buffer.readLine())!= null){

                        new Thread(new Downloader(line,count)).start();
                        count++;
                    }        
                    buffer.close();
                    System.out.println("totes les Tasques doandes.");  
                }else{
                System.out.println("Please Provide a File name by option -f.");
                }  
            }else 
            {
                System.out.println("Please provide parameters to execute  the program.");
            }   

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

al ejecutar lo en el terminal y con la instrucción java Main -f urls.txt me salta siempre a *"Please Provide a File name by option -f."* esto lo haga después de haber compilado mi clase Main con javac Main.java, he debugado el programa y he visto que el valor de args[0] es efectivamente -f pero la comparación me da el resultado false y no sé a que debe ser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrias probar con:

```
if (new String(args[0]).equals("-f"))
```

Comment: cabe señalar que la manera de igualar 2 valores, es poner primero la constante luego la variable, esto es para evitar un nullPointer.



if (("-f").equals(new String(args[0]))

saludos

Comment: el `new String()` es irrelevante

Comment: ¿Por qué esto soluciona el problema? ¿qué es lo que hace?

Answer (score 2):

En esta linea de codigo:

```
if(args[0] == "-f"){
```

Estas comparando `Strings` con el signo de igualdad (`==`) en vez de usar el metodo `.equals(...)` o `.equalsIgnoreCase(...)` <- intenta eso.

Es decir, cambialo a:

```
if ("-f".equals(args[0])) {
```

(actualizado para usar la constante antes de la variable, lo que es recomendado para evitar `NullPointerException` o `NPE`)

Comment: lo acabo de probar y sigue con el mismo error.

Comment: @Panda.V5 Vas a tener que dar mas detalles porque acabo de probarlo en mi IDE y esa es la solucion - sequro que es el mismo error?

Comment: lo he probado a hacer con new String(args[0]).equals("-f") y me ha funcionado, gracias por tu ayuda.

Comment: funciona, pero no es necesario crear una instancia de `String` para compararla con el argumento... en fin...